# Need to restart machine after letting it sleep

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, restart

I am running Ubuntu 20.0.4 LTS on a new Razer PC. I followed the instructions from the Ubuntu website to install Ubuntu from a bootable USB flash drive. My machine has 16 GB of RAM and 256 GB of disk space.

Whenever I leave my machine unattended for any meaningful (>1hr) period of time and it goes to sleep, when I open it back it is unresponsive and I have to restart it. I do not have this problem when I use Windows.

My linux knowledge is very limited and I have no idea what the problem might be or how to debug it. Please help me!

Comment: You weren't specific as to what Ubuntu 20.04 LTS you installed; was it a server system? desktop system? etc.  They both default to different kernel stacks?  and switching to the other stack may help  (`uname -r` will show you details of the running kernel, the GA stack for 20.04 is 5.4; HWE at 20.04.3 is 5.11, 20.04.4 is 5.13 etc - a newer stack *generally* does better on newer hardware but you gave no specifics on what 20.04 system you installed).

Comment: It's a desktop system - running `uname -r` returns `5.11.0-41-generic`